# Beep while building RAID 1 array

Tags: debian, raid-1, mdadm

I've built a NAS system using a supermicro superchassis. This chassis has Supermicro CSE-SAS-733TQ backplane supporting 4 hotswap bays.

Everything runs OK. I run a fresh debian 10 install. Now I tried to create a RAID 1  array of the two WD Red disks using `mdadm`. As soon the building of the array starts the system starts emitting small beeps. I located this must come from the backplane area. I've swapped the disks arround because I was afraid of disk failure but that seems OK.

I suspect this is a something of a controller warning. Because the array is being build.

Is somebody familair with this behaviour? I think the beep might stop after the array is successfully built. Any advise is appreciated.

System specs.

- SuperChassis 721TQ-250B
- backplane CSE-SAS-733TQ
- Asrock H370M itx/ac
- Intel i3 8100
- 2x WD RED 4TB (storage)
- 1x WD Black Nvme ssd 250GB

Comment: Hi!  I have a similar issue with WD Red but used for home surveillance video recording.  The beeps sound like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlWyYwZh3-g but SMART checks out clean: https://community.ui.com/questions/Beeping-sound-from-UDM-Pro-or-its-HDD-USW-RPS/9c546a0f-640d-450b-ac16-a944caa915ee.  Do your beeps also sound like this?

Comment: Absolutely. The thing is that mine disappeared after a while. Havent done  a smart check since. So don't know what fixed it.... :| Do you have the same chassis (supermicro) like the one I mentioned?

Comment: I put it in a piece of networking equipment called UDM-Pro from Ubiquiti.  The noise is intermittent for me too!  It didn't start happening until running for about 3 weeks.